# NVMe not being detected by KDE Partition Manager

Tags: kubuntu

I'm coming back to Linux after needing to use exclusively windows for the duration of my college course (pain). I have installed myself the latest version of Kubuntu Linux, 23.04. During my install, I experienced no issues whilst loading it onto my older 250GB Solid State SATA Drive.

After installing the OS, I started customizing it. I wanted to access my files, which I have stored on my NVMe drive, which holds my Windows 11 installation. I opened KDE Partition Manager to mount the drive, it did not show in the available menu. (All other drives did show.)

Answer (score 0):

IRST (Intel Rapid Storage Technology) was enabled in my UEFI BIOS.

Comment: My Dell worked with RST on, but I had to have Windows fast start up & Windows bitlocker off. With my NVMe (only drive) it used a  Intel® VMD driver. This was with Kubuntu 22.04.